# Continue instr. and Time Complexity in a for loop in C++

Tags: c++, time, complexity-theory, continue

I was wondering .... 
How does function "continue" in a for loop in C++ affect time complexity of the function, for example :

```
for( int i(0); i < size; i++)
{
    if( array [i] == i ) continue;
    while( j < array[i]/3 )
    {
        array2[j] = array [i];
        j += 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: You appear to be missing a '{' after the `for()`. What do you think the time complexity of the code is without the continue?

Comment: Posting as a comment because I am not entirely sure, but I would think it doesn't. Worst case is that the if always fails and you end up with complexity `nm`, where `n` is the outer loop and `m` the inner. Without information about the array, you could assume the if condition is satisfied either once or half the time on average,  which still gives `nm` times some constant.

Comment: does `j` start at `0`?

Comment: I thought that watching the worst possible case ( the one when continue never happens), the big O would be O ( size * log (array[i])), because of the "j += 2"

Comment: it probably does, @RyanHaining

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disregarding all constants you have to account for the worst case if you're looking for big O.

The `continue` in this example does not affect the big O, because you must account for the possibility that the preceding `if` condition is never passed.  Thus you have `O(n*m)`

The best case result is going to be `O(n)` in the event that the inner loop is *never* entered.  The `if ... continue` also doesn't have any affect on this value (though it may cause it to occur more often).  Without the `if ... continue` you still have the case that `j < array[i]/3` is never true.  Thus the inner loop is never entered which leaves the outer loop's body as `O(1)` giving `O(n)` with or without the `continue`

Answer (score 1):

If you intend time complexity as big O, you are interested in the worst case, then you should assume that "continue" would be never triggered.